# Panda- Categorical plot with given range

Tags: python, pandas

I have to plot in the axis with a given range. Here the student numbers are displayed as it is. But if i want the x-axis to have the maximum value 50 or 100, how do i do that?

```
e = {'student_id': ['10', '15','17','25','7','8','16'],
  'score': ['100', '50', '10', '60', '5','90','99' ]}
plt.plot('student_id','score',data=e)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the "range" of a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.xlim(left_limit, right_limit)`
can be used as you can apply
`plt.xlim(0, 50)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **pyplot.axis()**:

```
plt.axis([XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX])
```

or you can use **pyplot.xlim()**:

```
plt.xlim(XMIN, XMAX)
```

Answer (score 1):

`plt.xlim(min,max)` is what you are looking for

```py
e = {'student_id': ['10', '15','17','25','7','8','16'],
      'score': ['100', '50', '10', '60', '5','90','99' ]}
plt.xlim(0, 50) # or (0, 100)
plt.plot('student_id','score',data=e)
```